Pine script: Limit on strategy.exit does not work as expected
Trying to write a simple pine script query on a short strategy that enters during an uptrend and volume reaches a threshold. Multiple trades are allowed as long as the condition is met and the price is 2% higher than the average position price. Set a take profit with limit function however, losses are incurred. pin
//@version=5 
strategy("Simple Volume Spike", overlay=true,initial_capital=100000,calc_on_every_tick=true,pyramiding=100)

up = close / open >1.001

shortCondition=up and volume>1000000 
pc=0.005 
opencondition=strategy.position_size == 0 or (strategy.position_size < 0 and close>strategy.position_avg_price*1.02)
ordersize=1000/close 
if shortCondition and opencondition 
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short,ordersize) 
    strategy.exit("Close Short","Short", limit=close*(1-pc))


Your code works. look

@Gu5tavo71 yes it works but not as what I expected. I thought by setting limit=close*(1-pc), it will always close with a profit of pc%. However, I am seeing a lot of close with losses which I do not understand why. Any thought?

@Gu5tavo71 I notice that it closed all the orders when the latest exit condition is met (most of the time the older order will be closed at a loss)
